# problemas con vulnerabilidades NPM

Tags: reactjs, npm

131 vulnerabilities (1 low, 104 moderate, 22 high, 4 critical)
tengo problemas con npm , quise instalar una librería animate.css
y me aparecieron vulnerabilidades , ejecute  npm audit fix --force, y se redujeron a 8
estos 8 problemas provienen de postcss y nth check, que instalado los dos , pero cuando trato de forzar de nuevo  con  npm audit fix --force, me vuelven a salir las 131 vulnerabilidades.
si alguien tiene alguna solución lo agradecería.

Comment: tu proyecto es solamente node o usas algún framework? Algunos como angular tienen bugs raros de las versiones al usar angular-cli

Comment: Uso react, imagino que debe ser fallo de ahí con algunos módulos